# Android asset name must end in .xml

Tags: android, gradle

So I'm trying to build an android library, in its `res/assets` folder i have a few generated JSON files that the library uses. I've had these files here for months and have never had issues from them. Today I started getting this issue when building the library:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"The file name must end with .xml","sources":[{"file":"/Users/***/app/src/main/res/assets/data.json"}],"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/***/app/src/main/res/assets/data.json: Error: The file name must end with .xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
7 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 5 up-to-date
```

I haven't made any changes to this file recently so I'm not sure why this stopped working - Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put the `assets` directory into the `res` directory, which is being processed ...but only beside them (on the same level within the directory structure), so that they won't get processed.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it - not sure how my project has been successfully building the last couple months...

Comment: IMHO, this configuration should have never built ... probably you've never built the Android part?